# Issue with iText Library in Eclipse - ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException

Tags: java, eclipse, itext

I am new to programming and currently working on a simple Java project in Eclipse, where I am using the iText library(version 5.5.9) to generate PDFs from my JTable. Unfortunately, I am facing an issue that I couldn't resolve on my own.
When running my code, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread **"AWT-EventQueue-0"** java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException
```

I have correctly added the iText library in Eclipse under "Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add external JARs". However, Eclipse seems unable to find the DocumentException class.

here is the full Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/Document
    at Pdf.print(Pdf.java:41)
    at Pdf.main(Pdf.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.text.Document
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 2 more
```

**Here is the Code i tried:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
 
//import com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
//import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
 
public class Pdf extends JFrame {
  /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTable table;
 
  public Pdf() {
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    createTable();
  }
  private void createTable() {
    Object[][] data = {{ "a", "b", "e", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false) } };
    String[] columnNames = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
 
    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
 
    JPanel tPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    tPanel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    tPanel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 
    getContentPane().add(tPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
  private void print() {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    try {
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("jTable.pdf"));
 
      document.open();
      PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
 
      cb.saveState();
      Graphics2D g2 = cb.createGraphicsShapes(500, 500);
 
      Shape oldClip = g2.getClip();
      g2.clipRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
 
      table.print(g2);
      g2.setClip(oldClip);
 
      g2.dispose();
      cb.restoreState();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    document.close();
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pdf frame = new Pdf();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.print();
  }
  
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help and patience!

I expected that by adding the iText library in this manner, Eclipse would recognize the com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException class during runtime, and the issue would be resolved. However, despite these efforts, I continued to encounter the ClassNotFoundException for DocumentException when executing the code

Comment: there is the java build path and there is the runtime classpath...youll have to go to runtime configuration and add the lib to the classpath